# Drawing an image in a NSView

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, nsview, nsaffinetransform

I have a simple Obj C program that, at the moment, lets you load an image, draws it up, and theoretically should let you zoom and rotate. I'm using NSAffineTranslations.

I want the image to be locked to the upper left (As opposed to the PS/PDF standard of lower left), so I'm using isFlipped, and calling [afTrans scaleXBy:1.0 yBy:-1.0];

The problem is that for some reason, after the first time my drawRect is called, the transformation doesn't happen.

When I load an image, it comes up, and looks correct. If I change the size of the window (Which calls drawRect), the image draws, but is upside-down and reversed. This means that the transformation didn't take effect. I don't see any differences in any of the data the 2nd time through.

here is a stripped down version of the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect 
{
    // Drawing code here.

//    NSLog(@"window type: %d", [[self window] backingType]);
   NSAffineTransform *afTrans = [[NSAffineTransform alloc] init];
   NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
   NSSize sz;
   NSRect windowFrame = [[self window] frame];
   NSRect cv =[[[self window] contentView] frame];
   float deltaX, deltaY;
   NSSize superSize = [[self superview] frame].size;
   float height, width, sHeight, sWidth;

   NSRect imageRect;

   sz = [ image size];
   imageRect.size = sz;
   imageRect.origin = NSZeroPoint;

   height = sz.height  ;
   width = sz.width  ;

//    sHeight and sWidth are the hieght and with of the super-view. ie,
//    the size of the whole window view including the space for the
//    scroll bars, etc, but not including the panel or the borders,
   sHeight = superSize.height;
   sWidth = superSize.width;

   [context saveGraphicsState];

   deltaX = 0;
   deltaY = 0;

   deltaY += height; // account for flipping

   [afTrans translateXBy:deltaX yBy:deltaY];

   [afTrans scaleXBy:1.0 yBy:-1.0];

   [afTrans concat];

   NSRect drawingRect = imageRect;
   NSRect frame = imageRect;
   [self setFrame:frame];

   [image drawInRect:drawingRect
         fromRect:imageRect
         operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
         fraction:1];

   [afTrans release];
   [context restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

ETA: here's some more code that MIGHT be relevant.

```
-(void )setImage:( NSImage * )newImage
{
    [newImage retain];
    [image release];

    rotation = 0;

    zoom = 1.0;

    image = newImage;
    NSSize imageSize = [newImage size];
    NSRect tFrame = [self frame];
    tFrame = [[self window] frame];

    tFrame.size.width = MAX(tFrame.size.width, imageSize.width);
    tFrame.size.height = MAX(tFrame.size.height, imageSize.height);
    [self setFrame:tFrame];

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: [crickets] I already HAVE the tumbleweed badge... if this is that obscure a question, I feel better about not having figured it out myself B-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to just draw an image in a NSView and keep it in the upper left, you can do something a bit simpler, in your NSView subclass:

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)newImage
{
    [newImage retain];
    [image release];
    image = newImage;

    [image setFlipped:YES];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [image drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];

    // Or stretch image to fill view
    //[image drawInRect:[self bounds] fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
}
```

I was also able to get similar results with your code by getting rid of the `[self setFrame:...];` calls in drawRect and setImage methods.

Comment: Well, I needed to add the setframes because otherwise the scroll bars weren't correct. However, this simplification worked! thanks!

Comment: How would this be achieved with tiling an image?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not stripping out code that changes stuff, watch out if you're drawing the image elsewhere. Toolbar items, tables and so on may well change the -flipped property of the image, causing it to draw incorrectly.

Try this around your image drawing line:

```
BOOL wasFlipped = [image isFlipped];
[image setFlipped:[self isFlipped]];
[image drawInRect:drawingRect
             fromRect:imageRect
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
             fraction:1];
[image setFlipped:wasFlipped];
```

See if that helps. If it *does*, look elsewhere in your code for something changing the image's flipped property and not putting it back.

Comment: the isFlipped method isn't changing, it always returns YES.

when I add this code (which always sets the flipped to 1, draws it, andsets it back to 0) it starts up UPSIDE DOWN, and then flips correctly when I make it re-draw.

WTH is going on here?

Comment: There must be something else going on — I pasted your code above into a new NSView class and the image draws correctly all the time. Are you setting the isFlipped property of the view itself in a way other than hard-returning YES in the view's isFlipped? Is so, the initial draw may be occurring before isFlipped is set.

Comment: Nope, I'm hardsetting YES in isFlipped... and it always seems to be set to YES, when I NSLog it... 

But the other issue is that I think it's the affineTransform, because it appears that the affine transform isn't happening when I change the window size. at least, It's doing the same thing as it does it I comment out the affine transform...

Comment: Does it only happen *during* the live resize? If so, it could be live resize optimisations kicking in: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html